# Does sass harm performance?

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

I've been educating myself. Reading [this](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html):

> The engine evaluates each rule from right to left, starting from the rightmost selector (called the "key") and moving through each selector until it finds a match or discards the rule. (The "selector" is the document element to which the rule should apply.)

For example:

```
ul li a {...}
#footer h3 {...}
* html #atticPromo ul li a {...]
```

Now, some example code SASS outputs for me:

```
#content #blog {
  /* ... */
}
/* line 85, ../sass/screen.scss */
#content #flickr {
  /* ... */
}

#content #flickr div p {
  /* ... */
}
```

This seems a bit awkward.. am I doing something wrong? Is this a communication problem between me and Sass? Are we losing it?

**Edit**:
Some SCSS code:

```
#flickr {
    @include columns(5,8);
    background: url('../img/ipadbg.png') no-repeat;

    #ipod-gloss {
        z-index: 999;
        position: relative;
    }

    div {
        margin-top: -80px;
        margin-right: 20px;

        h2 {
            color: $white;
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        p {
            margin-top: 40px;
        }
    }
}
```

**Side Bonus!**: The article says browsers (or at least Firefox) search the selectors from right to left. I couldn't understand why this is a more efficient why. Any clues?

Comment: I don't see your Sass/SCSS code.

Comment: SASS/SCSS allows one to specify things easily (especially nesting) that would require the "long hand" CSS. While nesting may not always be the "correct way" to apply the given CSS (it may be too restrictive and brittle for the document), CSS selectors can be matched *very efficiently* with web-browsers. That being said: I wouldn't worry about it, unless there is a provable test-case of the CSS being "too slow".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to find your compromise between maintainability (nesting makes it easier to find your way around in the stylesheet) and rendering performance.

A rule of thumb says you should try to restrict yourself to a three-level nesting and you should avoid to nest IDs if it's not necessary.

However, I think nesting too much is not the biggest issue. As soon as I became aware of the power of mixins, I used them a lot.

For example, this is my often used button mixin:

```
@mixin small-button($active-color: $active-color, $hover-color: $button-hover-color, $shadow: true)
  display: inline-block
  padding: 4px 10px
  margin:
    right: 10px
    bottom: 10px
  border: none
  background-color: $button-color
  color: $font-color-inv
  +sans-serif-font(9px, 700)
  text-align: center
  text-transform: uppercase
  cursor: pointer
  @if $shadow
    +light-shadow
  &:hover
    text-decoration: none
    background-color: $hover-color
  &:last-child
    margin-right: 0
  a
    color: $font-color-inv
    &, &:hover
      text-decoration: none
  &.disabled
    +opacity(0.75)
    &:hover
      background-color: $button-color
  &.active
    background-color: $active-color
    &.disabled:hover
      background-color: $active-color
```

You see, quite a bit code. Applying such mixins to many elements on your page will result in a big CSS file which takes longer to be interpreted.

In the old fashioned CSS-way you would give each button element e.g. the class .small-button. But this method pollutes your markup with unsemantic classes.

Sass provides a solution though: selector inheritance via the [@extend directive](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend).

If you set defaults for your parameter of the mixin, you can also provide a simple class, which uses the mixins with your default:

```
// Use this mixin via @extend if you are fine with the parameter defaults
.small-button
  +small-button
```

And then you can just inherit from this class in various contexts:

```
#admin-interface
  input[type=submit]
    @extend .small-button
```

The resulting CSS statement aggregates all usages of .small button into one rule with comma-separated selectors:

```
.small-button, #admin-interface input[type=submit] {
  display: inline-block;
  ...
}
```

Concluding, a naive usage of Sass can effect your CSS performance. Used wisely, however, it is maintainable thanks to well-structured and DRY code, it leads to proper separation of markup and styling (semantic classes only) and allows for smart and performant CSS code.

Comment: I know that it has been 1.5 years since this answer, but I was wondering... You are mentioning performance several times, as it applies to CSS. Is there a real issue with the way SASS/SCSS translates nesting into badly-performing CSS or the file size gets too large?

Comment: Well, [there are studies](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/) that say that you won't have much impact when optimizing selector performance. Maybe it just does not matter for a modern browser like Chrome. But if you think at older IE browsers or mobile phones with a slower browser and a bad connection both selector performance and CSS file size do matter.

Comment: Also, if you consider the performance chart of one end user, you might have 500ms app server time, 500ms network time, 500ms browser DOM processing, and 2000ms browser page rendering time. Many people would say 500ms app server time is not good enough (not only because of scaling issues), but there are 2,5s time spend in the browser - quite some potential to cut down!

Comment: The only answer when asking about optimization is "use a profiler". There are CSS profilers for all the modern (including mobile) browsers. Use them, and guide your optimizations from those results.

Answer (score 6):

SASS is only a language that compiles down to CSS. If you're concerned with SASS' performance in terms of how it runs in the browser, then SASS doesn't enter the equation -- it'll be compiled and served to the browser as regular CSS.

---

From what I can see of your usage of SASS, there's a couple of things I could suggest:

1. You don't *have* to nest everything.

The ability to nest rules inside each-other in SASS is a language feature, but you don't have to do it if it doesn't make sense to do so.

---

In terms of your general CSS usage:

1. If the nesting gets too severe/unwieldly, consider using classes where it makes sense.
2. When it's necessary to use the hierarchy of DOM elements, consider using the [child combinator]: `.foo > .bar`.

IDs are meant to be unique, thus should always only reference a single element. Most of the time, they can be CSS rules unto themselves -- `#content #flickr` would become just `#flickr`, for instance -- and browsers will optimise the lookup for a single ID. The only time you would need something like `#id1 #id2` is if `#id2` needs to appear in different contexts on different pages.

If your selector contains things like `#id div p`, that `div` is either superfluous or serving a specific purpose.

- If it's superfluous, change the rule to `#id p`, which selects any `<p>` that occurs as a descendant of `#id`.
- If it serves a specific purpose, consider classing the `<div>` with a class name that describes its purpose -- perhaps `<div class="photos-list">`. Then your CSS could become `.photos-list p`, which is far more maintainable and reusable.

---

Comment: Right. But I think the question revolves about the fact that SASS *does* tend to generate much more verbose CSS than one might write without it, simply because it is easier to do. With that assumption made -- then, what performance impact, if any, do "deeper" selectors have? E.g. how do browsers match on them efficiently? What are CSS performance considerations?

Comment: The article I linked to answers that. Long selectors are considered slow. I'm more interested in ways of compiling sass without long nested selectors. #id1 #id2 seems weird, and should not be nested (although the edge case of using those for different pages inclusion makes this harder to identify). I'm asking: is this performance impact serious? or: is there a way to do it better with sass? the whole point of nesting is readability.. if I'll drop nesting for making the selectors better.. that's one less good feature in high-level css languages.

Comment: If you're nesting rules in SASS for readability only, you are misusing the language feature. You should only ever nest rules if:

(a) The parent is a strict and specific context on your page, and
(b) The child rules are context-dependent on the parent.

If your nested child rules don't absolutely require the parent in order to work, don't nest the rules.